# QUERY RECORDS WITHIN 48 hours

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am storing some data intro a mysql database like this:

```
ID     |   DATE      |  INFO
-----------------------------
1      | 1389384821  |  blabla
2      | 1389384821  |  blabla2
3      | 1389384821  |  blabla3
```

DATE is a timestamp generated before adding it into database using time() function in PHP

I want to get all data from this table that was added in the last 24 hours, or 48 hours, 30 days ...

I tried

```
SELECT
info
FROM table
WHERE date > (LOCALTIMESTAMP() - 86400)
```

Instead of LOCALTIMESTAMP(), I also tried CURDATE().

Where is my mistake?

I am not an expert in SQL, so this might sound a silly question.

---

WHERE date > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 86400) ?? Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is 24 hours

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR);
```

or your way

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 86400);
```

Here is 48 hours

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

or

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR);
```

or your way

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400 * 2));
```

Here is 30 days

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

or your way

```
SELECT info FROM table
WHERE date > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (86400 * 30));
```

Your last expression `WHERE date > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 86400)` is feasible, but requires you to do the number of seconds difference. My additional suggestions lets MySQL do the date computation.